# How to remove a grid item from the grid view on swiping?

Tags: qt, qml

I am animating the grid item to upwards on swiping up and removes the corresponding item on the animation stopped function. 
But the problem is when trying to remove the 0th index item. when removing 0th index item with animation, the whole screen moves up instead of the corresponding item animation.
Is there any solution for this ?

```
           Item {
                    id: fake_drag
                    x:0
                    y:0

                    width: 288*scaleFactor
                    height: 215*scaleFactor

                     property bool isReleased: false

                     NumberAnimation {
                         id: animationY
                         target: fake_drag
                         property: "y"
                         from: mouseYValue;
                         to: -200
                         duration: 500
                         onStopped: {
                             console.log("removed index : ", indexValue)
                              favouriteapp.remove(indexValue)

                         }

                     }

                    MouseArea {
                        id: mouseArea
                        property int difference: 0
                        width: 288*scaleFactor
                        height: 215*scaleFactor
                        anchors.centerIn: parent

                        onPressed : {
                            itemInitialYPosition = mouseY
                            indexValue = index
                        }

                        drag.target: fake_drag_image
                        drag.axis: Drag.YAxis

                        onReleased: {
                            onceloaded = false;
                        }

                        onMouseYChanged: {

                            mouseYValue = mouseY
                            difference = itemInitialYPosition - mouseY

                            if(!onceloaded) {

                                if(itemInitialYPosition >= mouseY){

                                    if(difference >= 25){
                                        console.log("swipe..")
                                        animationY.start()

                                        onceloaded = true;
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }



                            Image {
                                id: fake_drag_image

                                width: 64; height: 64
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

                                source: "images/Feature_Galary.png"

                                states: State {
                                    when: mouseArea.drag.active
                                    ParentChange { target: fake_drag_image; parent: itemid }
                                    AnchorChanges { target: fake_drag_image; anchors.verticalCenter: undefined; anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined }
                                }

                            }
```

}

This is the code used in grid item delegate.

Comment: Write some code, try it out, post your problem once you've encountered one.

Comment: Issue is only there in 0th index.